# Limit cycle of dynamical system $x'=xy^2-x-y$, $y'=y^3+x-y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider a planar ODE system $z'=f(z)$ with $z=(x,y)$, 
$$
f(x,y)=(xy^2-x-y,y^3+x-y).
$$
Using polar coordinates, one can get 
$$
r'=r(r^2\sin^2\theta-1),\quad \theta'=1.
$$

With Mathematica one can get
[image]

As one can see from the figure, there is a limit cycle for the system. I tried to apply the [Poincaré–Bendixson theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Bendixson_theorem) to show the existence of the limit cycle by using some negatively invariant annular region. But there seems no hope of finding such region. How should I go on?

Comment: Clearly, linearization won't work (since you're looking for a limit cycle). Looking forward to read the answers to this one.

Comment: I assume by "negatively invariant" you mean invariant under the flow as $t$ *decreases*, right?

Comment: by $z'$ so you mean $\frac{dz}{dt}$?

Comment: @Robert Lewis, Yes indeed.

Comment: @Dylan Yes. The notation $\dot{z}$ might be more common though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the change of variables $(u,v)=(x+y,y)$, the $(x,y)$-differential system is equivalent to the $(u,v)$-differential system $$u'=uv^2-2v,\qquad v'=v^3+u-2v$$ In particular, $$(u^2+2v^2)'=2(uu'+2vv')=2v^2(u^2+2v^2-4)$$
This shows that the ellipsis $(E)$ of equation $u^2+2v^2=4$ is invariant by the dynamics. In the $(x,y)$-plane, the equation of $(E)$ is $$x^2+2xy+3y^2=4.$$ Starting from every point inside $(E)$, one converges to $(x_\infty,y_\infty)=(0,0)$. Starting from every point outside $(E)$, one diverges in the sense that $x(t)^2+y(t)^2\to+\infty$. 
Finally, starting from every point on $(E)$, one cycles on $(E)$ counterclockwise with time period $$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\mathrm dt}{\sqrt2-\sin(2t)}=2\pi.$$ To evaluate the period, recall that, for every $a\gt1$, $$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\mathrm dt}{a+\sin(t)}=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}.$$

**Edit:** Some simulations of the systems $x'=x(y^2−c)−y$, $y'=y(y^2−c)+x$ for some $c\gt0$. The cycle of each such system is the ellipsis $(E_c)$ with equation $$x^2+2cxy+(1+2c^2)y^2=2c(1+c^2).$$
For $c=4$: `streamplot[{x(y^2-4)-y,y(y^2-4)+x},{x,-20,+20},{y,-5,+5}]`

$\qquad\qquad$[image]

For $c=.2$: `streamplot[{x(y^2-.2)-y,y(y^2-.2)+x},{x,-2,+2},{y,-2,+2}]`

$\qquad\qquad$[image]

Comment: Can this method be generalized to analyze any system $$r'=r(r^2\sin^2\theta-\epsilon),\quad \theta'=\cos 2\theta$$ with $\epsilon>0$ where $\epsilon=1$ is the special case in OP? Is it by trial and error or is there some motivation to make the $(u,v)$ transform?

Comment: The $(u,v)$-transform can be avoided. If your idea is to start from $$x'=x(y^2-\varepsilon)-y,\qquad y'=y(y^2-\varepsilon)+x,$$ then the correct translation is $$r'=r(r^2\sin^2\theta-\varepsilon),\qquad\theta'=1,$$ not what you wrote, and there is still an invariant ellipse, with equation $$x^2+2\varepsilon xy+(1+2\varepsilon^2)y^2=2\varepsilon(1+\varepsilon^2).$$

Comment: Ah, I see my wrong calculation for $\theta'$. I tried both $(u,v)=(x+y,y)$ and $(u,v)=(\epsilon x+y,y)$ and it turns out that these two coordinates do not work for the general $\epsilon>0$ case. What coordinates should I use instead?

Comment: Looking for an invariant set $x^2+2Bxy+Ay^2=C$, for some suitable $(A,B,C)$, is relatively straightforward. Alternatively, $(u,v)=(x+\varepsilon y,y)$ works.

Comment: It looks like you're using Mathematica to generate your figures but your syntax isn't quite correct - should be `StreamPlot`, rather than `streamplot`.  Presumably, you're using the syntax forgiving WolframAlpha interface?  If so, you're probably experiencing some latency between the entry of the command and the appearance of the plot.  If you use correct syntax directly, you should find that the commands execute immediately.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Thanks for the input. I just tried `streamplot`and `StreamPlot`, with no noticeable time reaction difference.

Comment: @Did Interesting. The `StreamPlot` command executes for me in a fraction of a second. If it takes more like several seconds for you, then you must be sending it through the WolframAlpha interface. If so there would be a little, stylized orange '=' sign on the left of your Input Cell.  [Here's an image](http://i.imgur.com/Fax1QpR.png) illustrating the different types of input. If it's executing quickly for you, then perhaps you've got an alias like `streamplot=StreamPlot`. Of course, in that case, it's working for you and you can happily disregard my advice!

Comment: @Mark Yes I am using the WolframAlpha interface. But thanks for the input nevertheless... and please do not hesitate to post again technical advice on using the WA interface.

Comment: @Did,  in general, how would you search/find an invariant set if you suspect there is one?

Comment: @abel This would make for an interesting math.se question.